# Manually boostrapped Angular app in InboxSDK change detection not working

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, gmail, inboxsdk

I'm trying to manually bootstrap an Angular application from the callback of an external library ie the [inbox sdk](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#APIReference).

**Current behaviour**

At the moment the application bootstraps and renders the initial state of the app but further changes to the app / component state do not cause re renders. `ngAfterViewChecked` or `ngDoCheck` are never fired again after the initial render.

Bootstrapping outside the of library's callback works fine with change detection. Unfortunately I do need to bootstrap on library calls...

Change detection is all set to default and otherwise it's a standard Angular 7 app built through the CLI.

Here is a [working example of the app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzp2fb)

The demo breaks if instead of bootstrapping the default way we bootstrap via the library callback as shown below.

`src/app/app.module.ts:Appmodule.ngDoBootstrap`

```
  ...
  inboxSDK.subscribe((sdk) => {
    this.bootstrapGmail(app, sdk)
  })
  ...
```

Unfortunately, it's hard to recreate this exact scenario in a jsfiddle as the [inbox sdk](https://www.inboxsdk.com/build/platform-implementation.js) won't work without the gmail environment and an API key.

Comment: i mean, it's a little hard to help you troubleshoot when you don't post any code. Admittedly the library itself is closed-source, but without a reproducible example, we're just tilting at windmills.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas updated with some code. Hope that helps

Comment: Seeing that StackBlitz code, isn't your AppModule class missing the `implements DoBootstrap` part, to tell Angular it need to execute the method?